# Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name RequestRateLimiter

Tags: spring-boot, redis, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to add a RequestRateLimiter in spring boot 2.7.2 microservices architecture, I downloaded the redis container, but I'm facing this exception when I tried to deploy

[image]

This is my application.yaml where I specified redis-rate-limiter

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:9296
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: ORDER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://ORDER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/order/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: ORDER-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/orderServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 10
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 20
        - id: PAYMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PAYMENT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/paymentServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - id: PRODUCT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PRODUCT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/product/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PRODUCT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/productServiceFallBackz
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
```

Also, I added redis dependency to load data.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```